# inflate a view in a custom infowindow null in mapbox

Tags: java, android, mapbox

Actually i have same problem [inflate a view in a custom infowindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39981810/i-cant-inflate-a-view-in-a-custom-infowindow-in-mapbox-setting-getinfowindow) It seems that I can't inflate this infowindow to a layout what i want

**Platform:** Android SDK 25
**Mapbox SDK** com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:4.2.2@aar

#### Steps to trigger behavior

1.When I click the marker  il will appear popup window shows app stopped

#### Expected behavior

I want to inflate the infowindow (the one after I click on a marker) but as of yet I want to use an XML for that for an easy customization (I am open for suggestions, I still need to add a different image for each of the markers.). I am using a customization in the code itself just for testing, but I want to inflate an XML for that purporse.

#### Actual behavior

```
`Process: com.viseo.jooboot, PID: 626
                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                   at com.viseo.poc.jooboot.ui.activity.MapActivity$addCustomInfoWindowAdapterTest$1.getInfoWindow(MapActivity.kt:204)
                                                                   at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.annotations.Marker.showInfoWindow(Marker.java:221)
                                                                   at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap.selectMarker(MapboxMap.java:1610)
                                                                   at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView$GestureListener.onSingleTapConfirmed(MapView.java:1946)
                                                                   at android.view.GestureDetector$GestureHandler.handleMessage(GestureDetector.java:300)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)`
```

#### Code JAVA

```java
mapboxMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MapboxMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public View getInfoWindow(@NonNull Marker marker) {

                        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.test_infowindow, null);

                        ImageView test = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_item_bg_jobinfo);
                        if (marker is JobInfoMarker) {
                       iv_item_bg_jobinfo.setImageResource(R.drawable.jobimage_default)
                    }
                        return v;
                    }
                });
```

#### Code XML

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ll_item_container_jobinfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_item_bg_jobinfo"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/tweet_image" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You're casting a view to a TextView and then assigning it to an ImageView. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: No what i want is inflate a view in the method getInfoWindow